# Directed graph connectivity

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given a directed graph G, what is the best way to go about finding a vertex v such that there is a path from v to every other vertex in G?

This algorithm should run in linear time. Is there an existing algorithm that solves this? If not, I'd appreciate some insight into how this can be solved in linear time (I can only think of solutions that would certainly not take linear time).

Comment: Check out Skienna's "Algorithm Design Manual".  It's got a fine chapter on graphs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a list L of all vertices.

Choose one; call it V.  From V, walk the graph, removing points from the list as you go, and keeping a stack of unvisited edges.  When you find a loop (some vertex you visit is not on the list), pop one of the edges from the stack and proceed.

If the stack is empty, and L is not empty, then choose a new vertex from L, call it V, and proceed as before.

When L is finally empty,  the V you last chose is an answer.

Comment: This will return some node even if there isn't one that actually satisfies the condition in the graph. I have no idea whether this matters to OP, but I think it should be mentioned.

Comment: Yes, that's true.  I think you can check whether the answer is sufficient by attempting to walk the graph starting from it (this is only necessary if you didn't guess it on the first attempt), again marking all vertices as you go.  This will still be linear, I believe.  And if the test fails, there is no solution.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done in linear time in the number of edges.

1. Find the strongly connected components.
2. Condense each of the components into a single node.
3. Do a topological sort on the condensed graph, The node with the highest rank will have a path to each of the other nodes (if the graph is connected at all).

Answer (score 0):

I think I've got a correct answer.

1. Get the SCC.
2. Condense each of the components into a single node.
3. Check whether every pair of adjacent nodes is reachable.

This is a sufficient and necessary condition.